# Fourier transform of Navier Stokes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

1)I want to perform Fourier transform w.r.t space for Navier stokes Equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I have difficulty dealing with the nonlinear term $u\cdot\nabla u$. Can anyone help with that?

2)[Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/navier-stokes-equations/) performs the Fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}^3/\mathbb{Z}^3$, but I couldn't see why it is like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier transform over the torus finds the coefficients $\mathcal{T}[u](k) = \hat{u}(k)$ in the Fourier series

$$u(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^3}\hat{u}(k) e^{-2\pi i  k \cdot x}$$

The transform of a product of terms like $u_1 \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}$ is a convolution of the transforms, that is

$$\mathcal{T}\left[u_1 \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}\right](k)= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^3}[\hat{u}_1(k-n)i]\cdot n_1\hat{u}_2(n), $$ where we used the fact that $\mathcal{T}\left(\partial u_2/\partial x_1\right)(k)=ik_1\hat{u}_2(k)$, here $k=(k_1,k_2,k_3)$.

Comment: What about in the whole space?

Comment: What about it.  Tao is considering periodic functions. The Fourier transform over a torus  is a 3D Fourier series on a finite cube.

Comment: Sorry for confusion just edit the question

Comment: Notice that the transform of the nonlinear term is a convolution sum not a convolution integral.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}^3$ the transform of a product is a convolution integral.

Comment: Could u show me the exact form? Thanks

Comment: So the Fourier transform of the product of functions $fg$ would be something like $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \hat{f}(y) \hat{g}(k- y) \, dy$. The transform of a term like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ is $-ik_j\hat{f}$.  Then you just need to put it all together.

Comment: @RRL: $ \hat{\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial u_1}}(n)$ should be $ \hat{\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial {\color{red}{x}}_1}}(n)$.

Comment: @mike: Thanks for catching the typo.